# Splitting String and retrieving values by key from a HashMap

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I'm having a problem where I need to put an abbreviation of a word and its full form into hashmap. Then I need to make a program that asks you the words and then prints the full words from the map for you. I can do it with one word but the problem is when it asks many keys with strings.

For example:

Given words:

```
tran. all of the wo. f. me
```

// At this point I have put all of the words with the dots to hashmap as key values and their full forms as values. Now it should print Given words as a full version where dotted words are replaced by values.

Full version:

```
translate all of the words for me
```

When you are asked multiple keys in one sentence, how to print all of the asked values?

// I think I should use .split to make this work but I'm not sure how it works.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: and your question is....

Comment: @SimpsonD there are plenty of people ready to help here, just make your question easy for them to understand.

Comment: I'm trying my best. The question:  When you are asked multiple keys in one sentence, how to print all of the asked values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `split()` method to get all the inputted words and store them in a `String[]`, then iterate over these words and try to change them by their respective values from your map.

Your code will be something like this:

```
Map<String, String> abbrev = new HashMap<String, String>();

String str="tran. all of the wo. f. me";
String[] words = str.split(" ");
String result = "";

for (String word : words) {
    if(abbrev.get(word) != null){
        result= result+ abbrev.get(word);
    }else{
        result= result+ word;
    }
    result= result+ " ";
}
```

**Note:**

Note that you can use `StringBuilder` as a best approach for building the result `String`.

**DEMO:**

This is a [**working DEMO**](http://ideone.com/BzIG5Y).

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you mean:

```java
String yourString = "tran. all of the wo. f. me";

for(String word : yourString.split("\\s+"))
  System.out.println(map.get(word));
```

Split is used to get every word from the string, separating by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve your goal. One of them is following:

```
     Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put("tran", "translate");
     map.put("wo", "words");
     map.put("f", "for");

     String word = "tran. all of the wo. f. me";
     String[] words = word.split(" ");
     for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
         if(words[i].endsWith(".")) {
             words[i] = map.get(words[i].substring(0, words[i].length() - 1));
         }
     }
     word = String.join(" ", words);
```